# Read non-directories (eg Iphone) on Windows with PERL

Tags: perl

I can read the content of a common directory, example

```
opendir(DIR,"C:\\");  
readdir(DIR);
## now try to open device
opendir(DIR,"Computer\\iPhone"); # ## this fails
```

However, devices like iPhones it does not show up as a regular path and when I try to access it with the path display in the address bar it fails.  Does anyone know how to search access these files?  thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Can you access the path in command prompt using CD and DIR? If you cannot then it's probably also not possible with perl.

Comment: iPhones normally do not allow direct Access to their file System. What is the reason Software like http://www.digidna.net/diskaid/features/iphone-file-transfer exist.

Comment: @squiguy error msg is: `Can't return outside a subroutine`

Comment: @SlavenRezic good question, no cannot seem to be able to - there are no usual prompt letter assignments (eg, C:, D: etc)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Perl question. Perl won't be able to read any directories that Windows can't. If your phone (whatever the make) doesn't show up on your system as a drive or a network share, Perl won't be able to read it's contents.